# Jquery second drop down depending on the first drop down does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have the problem of filtering the second drop down that depends on the first drop down,It is like the second drop down options they are static they does not do change based on what i have chosen here is my code to get secon drop down data.

```
   $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "{{action('CampaignController@getAdvertiser')}}/"+$("#advertiserId").val()

    }).done(function(results){
        $("#brandId").empty();
        $(results).each(function(index,value){                          

             newOption = $("<option value=\""+value.id+"\">"+value.brandName+"</option>");
             $("#brandId").append(newOption);



        });
```

please check my entire script maybe somewhere is refreshing that drop down

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#multiselect").multiselect({
                includeSelectAllOption: true
            });
            $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
                var selected = $("#multiselect option:selected");
                var message = "";
                selected.each(function () {
                    message += $(this).text() + " " + "\n";
                });
                alert(message);
            });
        });

        function loadBrands() {

            $.ajax({
                dataType: "json",
                url: "{{action('CampaignController@getAdvertiser')}}/" + $("#advertiserId").val()
            }).done(function (results) {
                $("#brandId").empty();

                $.each(results, function (index, value) {

                    var newOption = $("<option value=\"" + value.id + "\">" + value.brandName + "</option>");
                    $("#brandId").append(newOption);
                    // $("#brandId").trigger("chosen:updated");
                });
                //$("#brandId").empty();
                // hardcode 1 it must be remove asap
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "{{action('ReportingController@getCamp')}}/" + 1
                }).done(function (results) {
                    $("#campaignId").empty();
                    console.debug(get);
                    $(results).each(function (index, value) {

                        $("#campaignId").append("<option value=\"" + value.campaignId + "\">" + value.campaignName + "</option>");
                        $('#campaignId').trigger('change');
                    });
                });
                //loading city
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "{{action('CampaignLocationController@getLocations')}}/" + 1
                }).done(function (results) {
                    $("#city").empty();

                    $(results).each(function (index, value) {
                        getCityDetails = value.data[0];

                        $("#city").append("<option value=\"" + getCityDetails.brandId + "\">" + getCityDetails.city + "</option>");
                        $('#city').trigger('change');
                    });
                });

            }).fail(function (results) {
                alert("Failed to load brands.");
            });
        }
        loadBrands();
        $("#advertiserId").change(loadBrands);
        $("#brandId").change(loadBrands);


    });
```

Comment: `$(results).each(` is for DOM, you must use `$.each(results)` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(results).each(
```

Is used to iterate the Nodelist in jQuery.

For data manipulation, you must use `$.each(results)` instead.

```
$.each(results, function(index,value){                          

            var newOption = $("<option value=\""+value.id+"\">"+value.brandName+"</option>");
             $("#brandId").append(newOption);
            // $("#brandId").trigger("chosen:updated");


        });
```

Instead of appending in each iteration, you can push to an array and then append it at last.

```
var options = [];
$.each(results, function(index,value){                          
   options.push('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.brandName+'</option>');  
}); 
$("#brandId").html(options.join());
```

Also You've missed `var` keyword while defining `newOption` so it will be global

Comment: It is still doing the same thing,I can get my options but still giving the same problem eg my options are (red,green,orange,yellow,black,brown) when i choose say yellow it will pick it for maybe a sec but after that it goes back to red as if it is defaulted

Comment: could you please set up a jsfiddle to look at it? Because looks like something else is changing the drop down menu

Comment: my jsfiddle is running fine but i don't know why on my code is not working let me put the the whole code then.is it fine ?

Comment: Yes, it would be great if you could do that

Comment: Please share the URL to test

Comment: oh i got it the problem was the last line $("#brandId").change(loadBrands);

Comment: oh ya didn't notice. I was expecting an jsfiddle from you

Comment: posting the script that is in control of that helped me to see my error after 6 hours of debugging and using alternative methods of drop down.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(function () {
$("#multiselect").multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
});
$('#btnSelected').click(function () {
    var selected = $("#multiselect option:selected");
    var message = "";
    selected.each(function () {
        message += $(this).text() + " " + "\n";
    });
    alert(message);
});
 });

  function loadBrands(){

$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: "{{action('CampaignController@getAdvertiser')}}/"+$("#advertiserId").val()
}).done(function(results){
    $("#brandId").empty();

    $.each(results, function(index,value){                          

        var newOption = $("<option value=\""+value.id+"\">"+value.brandName+"</option>");
        $("#brandId").append(newOption);
        // $("#brandId").trigger("chosen:updated");
    }); 
    //$("#brandId").empty();
    // hardcode 1 it must be remove asap
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "{{action('ReportingController@getCamp')}}/"+1
    }).done(function(results){
        $("#campaignId").empty();
        console.debug(get);
        $(results).each(function(index,value){

            $("#campaignId").append("<option value=\""+value.campaignId+"\">"+value.campaignName+"</option>");
            $('#campaignId').trigger('change'); 
            });
    });
    //loading city
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "json",
        url: "{{action('CampaignLocationController@getLocations')}}/"+1
    }).done(function(results){
        $("#city").empty();

        $(results).each(function(index,value){
             getCityDetails  = value.data[0];

            $("#city").append("<option value=\""+getCityDetails.brandId+"\">"+getCityDetails.city+"</option>");
            $('#city').trigger('change');   
            });
    });

}).fail(function(results){
    alert("Failed to load brands.");
});
 }
 loadBrands();
 $("#advertiserId").change(loadBrands);  
 $("#brandId").change(loadBrands); removed this line now it is working
```